# How do i implement clickable link/button that opens a webpage in another tab in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to have a webpage which gets opened up in a new tab when a link/button is clicked. I am not sure how do i implement this in angular 8

Comment: https://html.com/attributes/a-target/#:~:text=browser%20specifies%20otherwise.-,a%20target%3D%E2%80%9D_blank%E2%80%9D%20Open%20in%20New%20Browser%20Tab%20(,older%20browsers)%20a%20new%20window.

`<a href="..." target="_blank" >` should work.

Comment: what should i put in href = "..." ? I need to open a webpage when the link/button is clicked

Comment: In the href, put the link of the webpage you would like to be opened in the new tab.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.netflix.com/">Welcome to Netflix Dhiman ji</a>
```

Comment: Please look for duplicates of questions such as these. Note also that someone has already suggested a duplicate which has an answer exactly the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You have another options as below

```
Typescript file 
link() {
window.open('http://www.netflix.com/',_blank);
}

HTML file
<button (click)='link()'>Welcome to Netflix</button>
```